# Where does the argparse and ConfigParser string replacement syntax come from?

Tags: python, argparse, configparser

When specifying help in argparse, I often use strings like `%(default)s` or `%(const)s` in the `help=` argument to display default arguments. The syntax is a bit weird, though: I assume it's left over from the days where python strings were formatted with `%`, but since python 2.6 the standard way to format strings has been using the `format()` function.

So are these libraries just using the 'old' replacement syntax, or does this come from somewhere else? It's been stated that the `%` replacement operator will disappear at some point, will these libraries change to the `'{}'.format()` syntax then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `argparse` and `ConfigParser` libraries use the old-style `%` string formatting syntax internally. These libraries were developed before `str.format()` and `format()` were available, or in the case of `argparse` the library authors aimed at compatibility with earlier Python versions.

If the `%` formatting ever *is* removed, then those libraries will indeed have to move to using string formatting using `{}` placeholders.

However, for various reasons, the `%` old-style string formatting style is here to stay for the foreseeable future; it has been 'un-deprecated'; `str.format()` is to be preferred but `%` is kept around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: It actually has never been deprecated in the first place.

Comment: Does this syntax have any precedent before python?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: There are plenty of copies of older documentation that name it as deprecated, but it was never made official.

Comment: @Shep: Yes, it is an extension on the `printf` C function format to support dictionary keys.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: PEP 3101 talks about 'when it comes time to deprecate the older system', which is indeed not really deprecating it.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: The sentence `str.format()` documentation talks about preference: *This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the `%` formatting described in String Formatting Operations in new code.*

Comment: Recent `logging.formatter` objects take a `style` parameter. `%` is default, but `$` and `{` are alternatives.  `argparse` might go that direction, eventually.  http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/logging.html#formatter-objects

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue13280  Raymond Hettinger 2011-10-27
"There's no reason to switch the implementation.  The % formatting isn't going away and we've decided against doing switch-overs in existing code (it risks introducing bugs while conferring zero benefits to users)."

Answer (score 1):

The approved way of customizing the help formatting is to subclass HelpFormatter.  A user can do this without waiting for a future Python release.

This formatter implements the {}.format in 2 places.

```
class NewHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    # _format_usage - format usage, but only uses dict(prog=self._prog)
    def _format_text(self, text):
        # for description, epilog, version
        if '{prog}' in text:
            text = text.format(prog=self._prog) # change from %
        text_width = self._width - self._current_indent
        indent = ' ' * self._current_indent
        return self._fill_text(text, text_width, indent) + '\n\n'
    def _expand_help(self, action):
        params = dict(vars(action), prog=self._prog)
        for name in list(params):
            if params[name] is argparse.SUPPRESS:
                del params[name]
        for name in list(params):
            if hasattr(params[name], '__name__'):
                params[name] = params[name].__name__
        if params.get('choices') is not None:
            choices_str = ', '.join([str(c) for c in params['choices']])
            params['choices'] = choices_str
        return self._get_help_string(action).format(**params) # change from %
```

For example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='NewFormatter',
    formatter_class=NewHelpFormatter,
    description='{prog} description')
parser.add_argument('foo',nargs=3, default=[1,2,3],
    help='nargs:{nargs} prog:{prog!r} defaults:{default} last:{default[2]}')
parser.add_argument('--bar',choices=['yes','no'],
    help='choices: {choices!r}')
parser.print_help()
```

produces:

```
usage: NewFormatter [-h] [--bar {yes,no}] foo foo foo

NewFormatter description

positional arguments:
  foo             nargs:3 prog:'NewFormatter' defaults:[1, 2, 3] last:3

optional arguments:
  -h, --help      show this help message and exit
  --bar {yes,no}  choices: 'yes, no'
```